# vue-router <router-view> não dá erro mas não renderiza

Tags: vue.js

Estou apredendendo Vue e me deparei com um problema. Eu instalei o `vue-router` via `npm`. Quando eu chamo a `<router-view>`, nenhum erro é indicado porém o site não renderiza na página. Se eu digito os links na barra de endereço, o conteúdo dos componentes são carregados.

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import {routes} from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**routes.js**

```
import Contato from './components/Contato.vue'
import Sobre from './components/Sobre.vue'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'

export const routes = [
  {path : '', component: Home},
  {path : '/contato', component: Contato},
  {path : '/sobre', component: Sobre}

]
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="" id="app">
  <div class="container">

    <router-view></router-view>

  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style lang="sass">
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass"
@import "~bulma"
</style>
```

Comment: Tem que ser `path : '/'` em vez de `path : ''`

Comment: Corrigi, mas cotinuo com o mesmo problema, Em todos os tutoriais que vi isso parecia ser tão simples...

Comment: veja agora, atualizei a resposta com um exemplo bem melhorado, dai pra frente só fazer as alterações que você necessita. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você esqueceu de informar a página inicial ( Componente ), vamos reescrever esse código, segue passo a passo:

1. Crie o arquivo *main.js*

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import App from './App'
   import router from './router'

   Vue.config.productionTip = false

   new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     router,
     template: '<App/>',
     components: { App }
   })
   ```
2. Crie o arquivo *App.vue*

   ```
   <template>
       <div id="app">
           <router-link to="/">/Home</router-link> - 
           <router-link to="/contato">/Contato</router-link>
           <router-view></router-view>
       </div>
   </template>

   <script>
       export default {
           name: 'app'
       }
   </script>

   <style>
   </style>
   ```
3. Crie o arquivo *index.js* dentro do diretório *router*

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import Router from 'vue-router'
   import Home from '../components/Home'
   import Contato from '../components/Contato'

   Vue.use(Router)

   export default new Router({
     mode: 'history',
     routes: [
       {
         path: '/',
         name: 'Home',
         component: Home
       },
       {
         path: '/contato',
         name: 'Contato',
         component: Contato
       }
     ]
   })
   ```
4. Crie os componentes dentro do diretório *components*

   > Componente *Home.vue*

   ```
   <template>
       <div class="home">
           <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
       </div>
   </template>

   <script>
       export default {
       name: 'home',
       data () {
           return {
               msg: 'Página inicial'
           }
       }
   }

   </script>

   <style scoped>
   </style>
   ```

   > Componente *Contato.vue*

   ```
   <template>
     <div class="contato">
       <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
     </div>
   </template>

   <script>
     export default {
     name: 'contato',
     data () {
       return {
         msg: 'Página de Contato'
       }
     }
   }

   </script>

   <style scoped>
   </style>
   ```

> Você pode ver funcionando aqui no [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jz6kro3o8y).

Comment: Verdade. Mas quando eu informei agora que a minha página inicial é 'Sobre', somente o conteúdo dela carrega o da 'Contato', não.

Comment: Certamente há algo errado. Veja esse exemplo no [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/RF9FcJ)

Comment: Você criou o arquivo exemplo: `Home.vue` e importou ele no arquivo `routes.js` ?

Comment: Olhei o seu exemplo e me parece muito parecido com o meu. Eu importei o `Home.vue` no `routes.js` e atribui o path `'/'` para ele. Então, quando no meu `App.vue`, eu chamo  `<router-view></router-view>` e ele deveria carregar Contato, Sobre e Home, certo? Acontece que está só carregando a home  e os outros components não.

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/249255/edit) sua pergunta e coloca o código como está agora.

Comment: Já fiz o edit do código do `routes.js`